# jQuery - AJAX call of Servlet

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, ajax, jsp

I'm building a web app for store scientific publications. I've used MySQL, JSP, jQuery and JAVA.

I have a form inside a JSP page, like this:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="text" id="code">
    <button onclick="request()">Search</button>
</form>
```

The function **request()** is:

```
function request() {
    var code = $('#code').val();
    var data='code='+code;
    $.ajax({
          url: "Servlet",
          type: "GET",
          data: data,
          success: function(){
              alert("success");
          },
          error:function(){
              alert("failure");
          }   
        }); 
};
```

The Servlet do some stuff and then save the resultset of query in the request object and forward the result on the index like this

```
request.setAttribute("result", resultSet);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

The **index.jsp** contains:

```
 <%  if(request.getAttribute("result")!=null){ %>
        <jsp:include page="table.jsp" />
  <%}%>
```

check if the result set is already filled, then include table.jsp, the page scan the resultset and put the values in a table.

This code doesn't work, someone can help me?
1- The query runs correctly
2- jQuery is called correctly

but the

```
if(request.getAttribute("result"))
```

is always null.

Comment: It seems you are mixing up ajax & synchronous processing. In general ajax response will be appended to servletresponse stream.

Comment: Instead of `request.setAttribute("result", resultSet);` try using session like, `session.setAttribute("result", resultSet);`.

Comment: Nambari you're right! I mixed two concepts that do not go well together. I went back to the simple "action" on the form, it calls the servlet. Thanks.